# How to remove tabs from customer edit page in Magento backend?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In magento, by default 11 tabs are displayed in the customer edit page in the back end. How can I remove tabs from the default list of tabs. What I have done so far:

1. Created a class to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs` class and then overrode the `_beforeToHtml()` method.
2. tried to remove the tabs using

   `$this->removeTab('addresses');`

Answer (score 3):

Removing Customer tabs

a) You have to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs because the Magento guys did a small typo there: they are adding tabs in _beforeToHtml() method instead of _prepareLayout(). So first you have to modify your config.xml and add:

```
<global>
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_edit_tabs>Yourmodule_Customer_Block_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
</global>
```

In Yourmodule_Customer_Block_Edit_Tabs just copy and paste the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs contents (don’t forget to change the class name!), and rename _beforeToHtml() method to _prepareLayout()

b) Add the removeTab action into your layout xml (default: customer.xml):

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <action method="removeTab">
            <name>NAME_OF_TAB</name>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

You can find out the NAME_OF_TAB, by inspecting the tab’s anchor () and looking for the “name” attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your solution works for every tab except 'Recurring profiles' and 'Billing Agreements'. Any idea why so?

Comment: Hi Emipro, do you know why I get this error "Mage registry key "subscriber" already exists" ? Thank you very much